# Consistent style of user-entered tables

Tags: wysiwyg, theming

Soon I will face a problem of ensuring constant look of tables entered by user throughout the site. I will probably install one of available WYSIWYG editors and allow tables therein.

I would probably want to prepare a set of table templates (with row headers, column headers, row&column headers, with column headers and subheaders, etc...) and would want the user to select appropriate template, determine row&col count, and then just fill in the data.

My task would be ensuring that the tables get appropriate classes upon submit and process them accordingly.

Would you do that with jQuery or with some WYSIWYG editor setup/plugin?

Comment: Now that I'm done with the job I can tell that the easiest way  was to deliver custom templates for CKEditor, although the very process of forcing CKEditor to see new templates was quite bothersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can create a wysiwyg plugin to do the job. In my case I used the hook_wysiwyg_plugin to create plugins I needed.

Comment: If it's possible to see some code just to get me started, it'd be really awesome. I can handle coding of the parser itself, but I know next to nothing about the architecture of plugins. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I can email you the module. No idea how to attach a file here. :D

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem and am developing a custom module to act when the specific content type is generated (`hook_node_presave`).  My concern is that the more they are required to do to generate the format, the more things will go wrong. All the user has to do is enter the cell contents as delimited rows and the module determines the size of the table and generates all the HTML and class content to match up with the css I have developed for its display.

Comment: It's good to know I'm not alone ;-) I bet, whatever you are about to leave out for users will soon get thoroughly tested - they usually do things you cannot foresee. Unless there is a nice plugin for a WYSIWYG editor, I would probably try a lightbox2 + editInPlace editor, if I only had more time. I'd be curious though to see your findings when you're done with your module.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter format that parse text into HTML. Something like this

```
|table|style=3
|data11|data12|data13|
|data21|data22|data23|
```

About a wysiwyg editor, I suggest CKEditor (I don't know much about TinyMCE, though). It has a good table editor, with predefined styles for row/column/both headers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to deal with user entered tables (or any other content, btw). You can either write a plugin for your WYSIWYG editor that applies classes to your content under certain circumstances (the client-side solution) or you can get the user input after it's been submitted and apply your own php logic to it (the server-side solution).

Drupal makes it very easy to go server side. It has an input filter feature that preserves the data the user has input but renders its output according to the filters' logic. Bonus: it caches the output.

Try studying filter inputs — Pro Drupal Development, the book, has a short yet complete chapter on it. You can see the [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) too.

Comment: And if you google any good tutorials, please post links.